# Will google index my site if my links are created dynamicly in javascript onready section?

Tags: javascript, search, optimization, hyperlink, indexing

Will google index my site if my links are created dynamicly in javascript onready section? 
I mean how does crawler work, will it wait until page is totally downloaded and then pass and index links(which will be ok for that time) or, it won't use such links?
So normal link with normal href but it's created in onReady method of JS.

Comment: short answer is no. but you can get google to index states of your page with html snapshots.
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: you gave me link to ajax crawling, but I didn't say anything about ajax. In my case some of components with links are just created in onready function without ajax invocation. So as result of onready method components are created with static links. Why will it be imposible for crawler to index such ones?

Comment: From your link:
"If you're curious about your own application, load it in a browser and then view the source (for example, in Firefox, right-click and select "View Page Source"). Similarly, if some of your content is created dynamically, the page source will not include all the content you will want the crawler to see. In other words "View Page Source" is exactly what the crawler gets....In other words, if the crawler can't find your content, it's not searchable." - I see normal links when I do so. So I assume it should be indexed

Comment: those links will be indexed. if you want to index content generated by javascript you can use the link to create snapshots for google.